# The meter does not remember data when changing orientation

Tags: android, kotlin, orientation

I'm trying to add the ability to maintain the state of the counter when changing the orientation, I used the method from the following link, but despite performing step by step, each step, the problem still occurs.

I used the methods onSaveInstanceState from this video [text](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_825OtO1GXw),

At this point my code looks as follows, in addition the question if I should use the method onDestroy.

```
package com.example.cookbook

import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.CountDownTimer
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.EditText
import android.widget.TextView

class Pasta_Fragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_pasta_) {

private lateinit var etMinutes: EditText
private lateinit var btnSetTime: Button
private lateinit var btnReset: Button
private lateinit var tvCountdown: TextView
private var countdownTimer: CountDownTimer? = null
private var remainingTime: Long = 0

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pasta_, container, false)

    etMinutes = view.findViewById(R.id.etMinutes)
    btnSetTime = view.findViewById(R.id.btnSetTime)
    btnReset = view.findViewById(R.id.btnReset)
    tvCountdown = view.findViewById(R.id.tvCountdown)

    btnSetTime.setOnClickListener {
        val minutes = etMinutes.text.toString().toIntOrNull()
        if (minutes != null && minutes > 0) {
            startCountdown(minutes * 60)
        }
    }

    btnReset.setOnClickListener {
        resetCountdown()
    }

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        // Przywracamy pozostały czas
        remainingTime = savedInstanceState.getLong("remainingTime")
        if (remainingTime > 0) {
            startCountdown(remainingTime.toInt())
        }
    }

    return view
}

override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
    // Zapisujemy pozostały czas
    outState.putLong("remainingTime", remainingTime)
}

private fun startCountdown(totalSeconds: Int) {
    resetCountdown()

    countdownTimer = object : CountDownTimer((totalSeconds * 1000).toLong(), 1000) {
        override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
            remainingTime = millisUntilFinished
            val minutes = millisUntilFinished / 60000
            val seconds = (millisUntilFinished % 60000) / 1000
            val formattedTime = String.format("%02d:%02d", minutes, seconds)
            tvCountdown.text = formattedTime
        }

        override fun onFinish() {
            remainingTime = 0
            tvCountdown.text = "00:00"
        }
    }.start()
}

private fun resetCountdown() {
    countdownTimer?.cancel()
    remainingTime = 0
    tvCountdown.text = "00:00"
}
```

}

I have tried several different ways, unfortunately I have not found a solution.

Comment: Where is the code for related to `savedInstanceState`? Also, using a ViewModel is better way for handling orientation changes. Because it saves it automatically and you don't have to worry about saving or restoring it.

Comment: I added the rest, it cut me off when copying

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).